# Como guardar en un arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Necesito guardar en un arrayList estos datos todas las veces que el usuario requiera pero los esta guardando en la misma posicion. Solo me imprime el ultimo guardado.

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

```
String nombre, apellido, id, celular;

ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();

public void agregarClientes() {

    nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar nombre");
    apellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar apellido");
    id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar identificacion");
    celular = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar celular");

    Persona cliente = new Persona();

    cliente.setNombre(nombre);
    cliente.setApellido(apellido);
    cliente.setId(id);
    cliente.setCelular(celular);
    
    personas.add(cliente);

    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea continuar?") == 0) {
        agregarClientes();
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < personas.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(cliente.getNombre() + "\n" + cliente.getApellido() + "\n" + cliente.getId() + "\n"
                    + cliente.getCelular());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si miras la línea del print;

```
System.out.println(cliente.getNombre() + "\n" + cliente.getApellido() + "\n" + cliente.getId() + "\n" + cliente.getCelular());
```

Verás que estás imprimiendo la misma persona misma cantidad de veces que personas tiene el ArrayList.

Para imprimir cada uno debes usar [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-)

```
for (int j = 0; j < personas.size(); j++) {
```

Persona p = personas.get(i);     System.out.println(p.getNombre() + "\n" + p.getApellido() + "\n" + p.getId() + "\n" + p.getCelular());
}

También puedes usar un for each, que es muy útil cuando no necesitas la posición de los elementos:

```
for (Persona p: personas){
    System.out.println(p.getNombre() + "\n" + p.getApellido() + "\n" + p.getId() + "\n" + p.getCelular());
}
```

---

Por último, te sugiero que no llames a la función dentro de si misma. Es una preocupación menor, pero al hacer eso, estás produciendo una función recursiva que puede dar un error [`StackOverflow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).

Una mejor opción usaría ciclos. Algo como esto:

```
public void agregarClientes(){
    do {
        agregarCliente();
    } while (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea continuar?") != 0);

    for (Persona p: personas){
        System.out.println(p.getNombre() + "\n" + p.getApellido() + "\n" + p.getId() + "\n" + p.getCelular());
    }
}

public void agregarCliente() {

    nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar nombre");
    apellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar apellido");
    id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar identificacion");
    celular = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar celular");

    Persona cliente = new Persona();

    cliente.setNombre(nombre);
    cliente.setApellido(apellido);
    cliente.setId(id);
    cliente.setCelular(celular);

    personas.add(cliente);
}
```

Comment: celebro que hayas tenido más tiempo para hacerle el código, pero sigue siendo la misma respuesta y solución que yo planteaba, sin darle todo el código al OP, es decir dejandole chance para aprender.

Comment: @DEVX75 Simplemente ya tenía escrita la mayor parte de la respuesta para cuando apareció la tuya y me dio pereza borrar. También noté que estaba usando funciones recursiva y le mostré una alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Es correcto, te imprime únicamente el último cliente, "n" veces, tantas veces como inserciones hay en la lista, debido a esta línea:

```
System.out.println(cliente.getNombre() + "\n" + cliente.getApellido() + "\n" + cliente.getId() + "\n"
                    + cliente.getCelular());
```

Ahi, cliente, es el último que leiste, y como está dentro del for... Lo que deberías estar referenciando por indice a cada elemento de la lista personas, dentro del for y justo antes del system.out.println()

```
cliente = personas.get(i);
```

Por otro lado, una sugerencia de mejora al control de recursos:
Tienes una llamada recursiva a tu función, aunque no afecta tanto, pero es mejor usar un bucle, que lea cada vez, datos del cliente, agrega la persona y continua solamente en dependencia de la respuesta del usuario: Un Do While es una buena opción. El for para imprimir la lista, puedes dejarla para despues de la lectura de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, efectivamente ese era el problema. Gracias por el consejo, llevo poco programando y la idea es seguir aprendiendo.

Comment: Excelente! Sigue adelante!